# Restore boot parameters to default value Linux

Tags: ubuntu, boot, performance

I feel my system is getting slower and slower. I am using Ubuntu and my machine is HP ProBook 450 i7 4x2.0GHz, 8GB RAM and an optical HD. Still it takes ~2 minutes to boot, which in my opinion is way too much.

I was thinking on reinstalling the OS from scratch, but that is way too tedious since I have a lot of custom C++ libraries which would take ages to set-up again. Also, I expected Linux not to lose performance in such a way so quickly (I have this laptop for a year now).

My question is, is there any way to restore the boot options to default? Or anything else I could do to clean-up whatever is clogging the performance? I know SSD would help here, so please don't give me such answers, since there is obviously something wrong with the software.

Here is my dmesg log http://pastebin.com/1L9nHa0j if that could help as well. Also, I have noticed a performance decrease the moment I switched from 3.16 kernel to any other above it (I tried 3.18, 3.19, 3.20, 4.15, 4.3)

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which version of Ubuntu you are using? and Which init system that distribution is using.

I think you should use some latest version. The new and fastest init system is `systemd` , it has the paralellization capabilities that increases the boot speed of a system.